# Find the determinant of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

> Find the determinant of the linear transformation
>   $$
> T(M) =
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         2 & 3 \\
>         0 & 4 \\
>         \end{bmatrix} M
> $$
>   from the space $V$ of upper triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices to $V$.

I know this question is quite straightforward but for some reason I simply cannot get my head around what I'm supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider the space of upper triangular matrices only, then choose the basis vectors
$$e_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$e_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$e_3=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$$

Because
$$T(e_1)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&3\\0&4\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)=2e_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$
$$T(e_2)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&3\\0&4\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&2\\0&0\end{array}\right)=2e_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\2\\0\end{array}\right)$$
$$T(e_3)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&3\\0&4\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&3\\0&4\end{array}\right)=3e_2+4e_3=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\3\\4\end{array}\right)$$

Then $T$ can be represented by the matrix
$$T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} T(e_1) & T(e_2)&T(e_3)\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}2&0&0\\0&2&3\\0&0&4\end{array}\right)$$

The determinant is
$$\det(T)=2\times 2\times 4 = 16$$

Remark:

If we consider it as a linear transformation from all $2\times 2$ matrices to itself, then choose the basis vectors
$$e_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$e_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$e_3=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$e_4=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$$

Then $T$ can be represented by the matrix
$$T=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}2&0&3&0\\0&2&0&3\\0&0&4&0\\0&0&0&4\end{array}\right)$$

The determinant is
$$\det(T)=2\times 2\times 4\times 4=64$$

Comment: Sorry could you also explain how T can be represented by the basis vectors  for the upper triangular matrix space part

Comment: @N.Babuchak I've edited my answer. Please see if it's ok now.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't know how to represent matrices using basis elements having multiple vectors. Would it be possible for you to explain the step after obtaining the basis vectors, and before the step showing T's matrix? If it's too much to ask, could you guide me to any resources I can use to learn that? many thanks

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it!